# Python: Iterate over values in a series and replace with dictionary values when key matches series value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate over a column in a dataframe and when the value matches a key from my dictionary it should then replace the value in another column with the value of the matching key.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['123', '456', '789'], 'Full': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes'], 'Cat':['','','']})
    cats = {'123':'A', '456':'B', '789':'C'}
    for val in df.id:
        for key, cat in cats.items():
            if key == val:
                df.Cat.loc[(df.Full == 'Yes')] = cat
    df
        id  Full Cat
    0   123 Yes  C
    1   456 No  
    2   789 Yes  C
```

I would expect id 123 to have a Cat of 'A' but instead it only returns 'C'

Can anyone explain to me why the it isn't iterating over the keys in dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.replace` and pass the dictionary, and assign the result to `Cat` column:

```py
>>> df['Cat'] = df.id.replace(cats)
#output:

    id Full Cat
0  123  Yes   A
1  456   No   B
2  789  Yes   C
```

Or, if you intend to replace in only the rows with `Full` as `Yes` one way is to simply apply a function on `axis=1` then implement the logic for each rows:

```py
>>> df['Cat'] = df.apply(lambda x: cats.get(x.id, '') if x.Full == 'Yes' else '',
                     axis=1)

    id Full Cat
0  123  Yes   A
1  456   No    
2  789  Yes   C
```

Comment: This works fantastically, can't believe I couldn't figure that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For filtered values in column use `dict.get`:

```
mask = df.Full == 'Yes'
df.loc[mask, 'Cat'] = df.loc[mask, 'id'].apply(lambda x: cats.get(x, ''))
print (df)
    id Full Cat
0  123  Yes   A
1  456   No    
2  789  Yes   C
```

If no match in dict is possible create `None`s use:

```
cats = {'123':'A', '456':'B', '7890':'C'}

mask = df.Full == 'Yes'
df.loc[mask, 'Cat'] = df.loc[mask, 'id'].apply(cats.get)
print (df)
    id Full   Cat
0  123  Yes     A
1  456   No      
2  789  Yes  None
```